# corrupted double-linked list in c++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux

```
gdb) s
ACE_New_Allocator::free (this=0x8621380  <ACE_Allocator::instance()::allocator_instance>, ptr=0x86549e0) at Malloc_Allocator.cpp:151
151       if(NULL != ptr)
gdb)l
148    void  ACE_New_Allocator::free (void *ptr)
149     {
150     /*S7CHANGES START*/
151       if(NULL != ptr)
152               delete [] (char *) ptr; // crash happens. But Ptr is not NULL
153     /*S7CHANGES END*/         
154     }
gdb) p ptr
$1 = (void *) 0x86549e0
(gdb) p (char*)ptr[0] // tried to access ptr[0] & application crashed.
*** Error in `/home/ic018596/views/s7p.omsp/oms/interm/Linux/Make/Debug/test/UnmanagedTests/CPPUnit/ToolsPlusTest_EsT1_Tcp/out/ToolsPlusTest': corrupted double-linked list: 0x086559e0 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

please look at the above code. i couldn't understand why crash happens,Even though ptr is not NULL. if i try to access or free the ptr it is crashing. please help me out.

Comment: Deleting a null pointer will not cause a crash: see [here](http://ideone.com/rLVcjf) and [here](http://ideone.com/m3tjOh). What will cause a crash is deleting a pointer which points to memory that you do not own, see [here](http://ideone.com/B3eFeC) and [here](http://ideone.com/g9bzX9).

Comment: the many meanings of null pointer , maybe his NULL is not nullptr!

Comment: The crash can be caused by corruption of memory in a multitude different ways somewhere earlier in the program. It is impossible to say what is the reason; better use some tool like valgrind.

Comment: The error comes from deep in the bowels of the memory manager and its ultimate cause is that you're mismanaging the memory in your application in such a way that the memory manager's internal structures are destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete [] (char *) ptr;
```

> i couldn't understand why crash happens

Crashes are often result of undefined behaviour. Typical reasons why `delete[]` might have undefined behaviour are:

- Memory pointed by `ptr` was never allocated using `new char[]`. Perhaps the pointer was uninitialized and points to random location in memory. Or, maybe the memory was allocated with `new` rather than `new[]`. Or, maybe it points to an array with automatic or static storage.
- Memory pointed by `ptr` was allocated properly, but has already been deleted.

Alternatively, the heap could have been corrupted by some other undefined behaviour earlier.

> Even though ptr is not NULL

You've made an incorrect assumption. If `ptr` were `NULL`, then deleting could not possibly crash the program.

Comment: Thanks.. 
i have a doubt, if ptr has deleted alredy.. the memory location it points to should be NULL(0x000) ryt?

Comment: i have written a sample programme. if we delete the ptr, it will not be NULL ptr. Thanks

Comment: @SanthoshKumar indeed, deleting a pointer will **not** set it null. It will still point where it did and dereferencing or deleting it will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar we can't tell if a pointer is deleted or not. We must analyze our source code and prove that a pointer is never deleted nor dereferenced after being deleted. Proving that becomes very difficult if we copy raw pointers. You should avoid doing that at all costs. Use of smart pointers and standard containers makes the proof much easier and you can rarely double delete even by accident when using them.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a double delete without setting the pointer equal to NULL. To verify it should be possible to see that in the debugger by examine the memory address of the pointer.

A possible scenario is that you have multiple threads removing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ptr` is not NULL but it should be?

Maybe your `node->next` or `node->prev` are not set correctly after add or
   remove a node (so the subsequent remove operation fails) or there is uninitialized node data (of pointer type for
   which `ACE_New_Allocator::malloc` was not called and the pointer was not set to NULL) you're trying to
   free when removing a node.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with user's linked list, it has something to do with memory manager linked list

Comment: but delete ptr[] also crashing.

Comment: ::free(ptr);
this the function, which i used to delete [] ptr.

Comment: Not clear. Need more code to understand what `ptr` is, what it points to, where it comes from, etc... Maybe you can update your question to add some code. As I understood you created some double-link list and manage it. Need to see the code.